# Angularjs Controllers Don't Work

Tags: angularjs, controllers

Edit: I found the problems. Thank you everyone for pointing them out to me! :)

I'm a little new to angularjs. Right now, my ng-view and ng-include are working, however my controllers are not. They were working before, but I cannot figure out why this isn't working.

I'm developing on a mac, testing with safari. (Chrome doesn't work when developing locally due to security purposes).

The controllers stopped working when I separated them into different files.

*index.html*

```
<html ng-app="socialApp">
<head>
    <script src="assets/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-include="'partials/header.html'"></div>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
</body>
```

*header.html*

```
<div ng-controller="HeaderController">

{{header}}
</div>
```

*headerController.js*

```
var socialApp = angular.module('socialApp', []);
socialApp.controller('HeaderController', function($scope) {
  $scope.header = 'Hello World!';
});
```

Comment: "*Don't work*" is not descriptive enough.  Let us know what exactly is happening (or not happening) and what was changed since the time it allegedly worked.

Comment: Basically when I split my controllers into separate files, the controllers stopped working. I followed the advice by removing the array parameter in the module initialization, however it still is not loading the {{header}} variable.

Comment: Make sure to also post any answers from the console. They should help steer in the correct direction. Also notice that all 3 answers (From Tong Shen, Jarema, Sunil D.) are correct. 'controller' must be the name of the controller, not the url; You must add a script tag for each external js file; finally, you should remove the array of dependencies from subsequent calls to angular.module

Comment: This worked. Thank you. I edited my question and removed the comment about the url thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
  when('/friends', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/friends.html',
    controller: 'controllers/siteController.js'
  })
```

You may need to write this:

```
  when('/friends', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/friends.html',
    controller: 'FriendsController'
  })
```

And also you need to link all the js files of your controllers in your html file.

And and, you should create the socialApp module only once with `angular.module(MODULE_NAME, [DEPENDENCY_MODULES, ...])`. In the later files when you need to use it, just get a reference through `angular.module(MODULE_NAME)`.

Comment: Yep. Thats also true.

Comment: I tried this, however it does not work. I think there needs to be a file location if the controller is external.

Comment: Thank you!! This works. I really want to upvote you right now, but I don't have the rep :( I'll be sure to return and give this an upvote when I can.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you do this:

```
var socialApp = angular.module('socialApp', []);
```

You are declaring a new module (and blowing away the previous declaration). Your application code only needs to do this once, I would recommend keeping that in config.js

In all the other javascript files that you wish to use the module, you can access it like this:

```
var socialApp = angular.module('socialApp');
```

Notice the subtle difference. Removing the Array parameter tells Angular to retrieve the module, not define a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I m on phone so i might be wrong but... i dont see You including sitecontroller.js and headercontroller.js in Your html file. I see only config file included.

Comment: Im glad we could help You :).